# UIView layout in storyboard with rotations in code, how to set proper constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, rotation, storyboard

I would like each arrow to point to the outside. The top one is correct but the other ones are not. It seems that you cannot rotate them in the storyboard, so I will have to rotate them in code. My question is what to do with the constraints?
If I set them in the storyboard when I rotate the views will the be relative to what's in the storyboard or the rotated view in code?

Does anyone have any tips on doing this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: you need to update the constraints after you complete the rotation